# "Download App" button for Facebook App page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to be able to change the link for the button "download app" on facebook app page.  Facebook made some changes and now I am not able to find the place where I can change this link.

Would any one mind letting me know if this is still possible and if it is, where can I go do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide me few details how to add download button on fb page? so I can up vote your answer & question as well.